# What is the reason behind having greater active threads when performing load testing on GlassFish Vs Tomcat using JMeter?

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish, jmeter

I'm currently working on creating a benchmark that compares the performance of various open source web servers tested using JMeter. When I performed load testing on both GlassFish and Tomcat I observed that the average number of active threads spanned by JMeter is greater when testing GlassFish Vs Tomcat.

```
At = Active threads.
Sp = Sample Time in ms.

GlassFish = 32.56 At
Tomcat = 10.36  At  

GlassFish = 167.64 Sp
Tomcat = 165.37 Sp
```

My findings represents the average of 500 requests spanned over 10 seconds. I would appreciate if someone can give me the actual reason behind my findings. Does it mean that GlassFish has greater concurrency compared to Tomcat?

Comment: how did you setup your jmeter test?

Comment: @RaGe, I used this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-jmeter-to-perform-load-testing-on-a-web-server) tutorial to setup the test , where my Number of Threads (users) = 500, and Ramp-Up Period (in seconds) = 10.